# How to set a variable outside the scope of my function?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm trying to use position.coords in an external scope outside the function but I'm not able to move the values in one global var to call outside the function scope. I have tried many solutions including window variables. In this case geolocalisation, new google.maps.LatLng(iplat, iplong) is null. Can someone sugest the way to put position.coords outside function getLocation scope.

```
function getLocation(position)
{
    window.iplat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
    window.iplong = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);
}
function errorFunction(position) {
  alert('Error!');
}    
var geocoder;
var address;
var userlocation;
var curloc;

google.load("maps",'3',{other_params:'sensor=true'});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
    if (google.loader.ClientLocation)
    {
         geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        //html5    
        if(navigator.geolocation) {          
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocation);
        }
        else
        {
          curloc = google.loader.ClientLocation;
          iplat=parseFloat(curloc.latitude);
          iplong=parseFloat(curloc.longitude);          
        }
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(iplat, iplong);
          if (geocoder) {
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng},function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[1]){
                country_code=results[1]....;
              }
            } else {
              alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
            });
        }
        alert(country_code+":"+iplat+"||"+iplong); <--- NULL VALUES
      }

});
```

Comment: Zlatev is right. Your problem is not in 'setting a variable outside the scope of getLocation', it's in the fact that the code that tries to use the location runs before getLocation().

Answer (score 1):

Not quite familiar with the google api, my wild guess is you are passing variables which are not present at the time. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` accepts callback arguments (as well as `google.setOnLoadCallback` ). To make sure all needed variables are present nest events backwards.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(position){
    var iplat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude),
        iplong = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);

    alert(country_code+":"+iplat+"||"+iplong); //should work now!
    google.load("maps",'3',{other_params:'sensor=true'});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { ... } ); // the rest of code
  }
);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok tested but always problems to get values outside this scope. My code is very long and needing in others steps the value. I lovelly another solution.